# Suppressing notification for emails from certain senders

Tags: gmail-filters, notifications, inbox-by-gmail

I use sound notification for incoming mail in Gmail. There are some senders whose emails are not that urgent, so I avoid notification by marking their messages read upon arrival, using a filter. It is only marked read, not archived.

I understand that Inbox by Gmail doesn't have filters with "mark as read" action. Is it possible to achieve the same result — suppress notifications but do not archive — using the tools available in Inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Notifications - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067586?hl=en), yes, it's possible.

> ### Android
>
> #### Step 1: Make sure notifications are on for your account
>
> 1. Open the Inbox app.
> 2. Go to the main menu in the top left [image: Main menu].
> 3. Choose [image: Settings] Settings at the bottom.
> 4. Select your email address.
> 5. Make sure Notifications is checked.
> 6. Choose whether you want to be notified with vibration, light, or sound.
>
> #### Step 2: Change your label notifications settings
>
> When notifications are turned on, you'll always get notifications for
> new emails that come into your inbox individually.
>
> For emails that are bundled in a label in your inbox, you can choose
> to turn notifications on or off. For example, you could be notified
> about emails in Finance or your own custom "Urgent" label, but not
> emails in Promos.
>
> 1. Stay on the same page in Settings and scroll down to Label settings and notifications.
> 2. A bell [image: Bell] means that notifications are turned on for that label.
> 3. To change a label's settings, touch the label name and switch Notifications on or off.
>
> Note: Notifications are always off when the label is set to "Skip the
> inbox."